# How to move data(managedobject) each other tableview when I used 2 tableviews?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data

Situation : two tableviews(I used coredata.)

If there are two tableviews, is it possible to move data between them?

For example, In first tableview I input some data like A, B, C, D, E, F.

Of these, I want to move DATA(C, D, E, F) to second tableview and I wonder how only A,B do that to show in first tableview

Note that : Data is not fixed...

A, B, C, D, E, F ------> Tableview 1  **(if I input change method)**

C, D, E, F       ------> Tableview 1  &&&   A, B -------> Tableview 2

Answer (score 0):

Two options I can think of:

A.  Use delegate
B.  Re-read data in table view 2 after you have saved in tableview 1.

Comment: But I cannot modify tableview 2 directly(in tableview). So I want to change by some actions(touch and drag) with Notification... is it possible to use "predicate method"?

Comment: I don't think I understand your question.  But there is a reload method for tableview... So, you can refresh data in the tableview 2 once you get notifying or using delegate method.... And yes you can your predicate to filter out only the data you need to from coredata...